# I am trying to set up the working enviroment for Rejact JS. When I run npm install in command prompt. Its show this error, any advise?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to set up the working environment for Rejact JS, but I get this error when I run `npm install`:

[image: npm-error]

Comment: Are you in the right directory? Seems it can not find any `package.json` . file.

Comment: copy and paste, don't link to an image.

Comment: {
  "name": "simple-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "react for beginner",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
   "babel-core": "^5.8.*",
   "babel-loader": "^5.3.*",
   "webpack": "^1.12.*",
   "webpack-dev-server": "^1.10.*"
  },
  "dependencies": {
   "react": "^0.13.*"
  }
}

Comment: I have package.json file.

Comment: I run your package.json without a problem. Make sure you have the package.json file exactly in C:\users\sayn\package.json

Answer (score -1):

Of course I have my package.json here:

```
[package.json][1]
```

I just run npm install or npm install -d to load the model but the issues is as below here:

[npm install error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkVcB.png)